Shadcn ComboBox form + Virtualized TanSack list in NextJs14 application
I have a client component in nextjs that implements a form which contains a dropdown coupled with search properties, it uses the fammous shadcn library + some tanstack virtualizer because the list of items I have is really big. I am almost trying to make this work , however when I click and dropdown selection appears the values are not displayed, only when i start typing to search is that the values are displayed. I do not understand why this is happening, here is the code for my component.
'use client';

import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { CaretSortIcon, CheckIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { z } from 'zod';

import { cn } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
} from '@/components/ui/command';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover';
import { toast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useVirtualizer } from '@tanstack/react-virtual';

type Option = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

const FormSchema = z.object({
  service: z.string({
    required_error: 'Please select an IT Service.',
  }),
  // tech_version: z.string({
  //   required_error: 'Please select a technology version',
  // }),
});

export function ComboboxForm(
  { data }: { data: string[] },
  // data: {
  //   it_service: string;
  //   tech_version: string;
  //   eg_status:
  //     | 'EOS'
  //     | 'EOS in 6 months'
  //     | 'EOS in 12 months'
  //     | 'EOS in 24 months'
  //     | 'EOS in 36 months'
  //     | 'EOS longer than 36 months';
  // }[];
) {
  const options = data.map((item) => ({
    value: item,
    label: item,
  }));

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  });

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [filteredOptions, setFilteredOptions] =
    React.useState<Option[]>(options);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState<string>('');
  const parentRef = React.useRef(null);

  const virtualizer = useVirtualizer({
    count: filteredOptions.length,
    getScrollElement: () => parentRef.current,
    estimateSize: () => 35,
    overscan: 5,
  });

  const virtualOptions = virtualizer.getVirtualItems();

  const handleSearch = (search: string) => {
    setFilteredOptions(
      options.filter((option) =>
        option.value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase() ?? []),
      ),
    );
  };

  function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    toast({
      title: 'You submitted the following values:',
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      ),
    });
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="service"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
              <FormLabel>Language</FormLabel>
              <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
                <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Button
                      variant="outline"
                      role="combobox"
                      className={cn(
                        'w-[384px] justify-between',
                        !selectedOption && 'text-muted-foreground',
                      )}
                      style={{
                        width: '384px',
                      }}
                    >
                      {selectedOption
                        ? options.find(
                            (option) => option.value === selectedOption,
                          )?.value
                        : 'Select IT Service'}
                      <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                    </Button>
                  </FormControl>
                </PopoverTrigger>
                <PopoverContent
                  className="w-[384px] p-0"
                  style={{ width: '384px' }}
                >
                  <Command shouldFilter={false}>
                    <CommandInput
                      placeholder="Search framework..."
                      className="h-9"
                      onValueChange={handleSearch}
                    />
                    <CommandEmpty>No IT Service found.</CommandEmpty>
                    <CommandList>
                      <CommandGroup
                        ref={parentRef}
                        style={{
                          height: '208px',
                          width: '100%',
                          overflow: 'auto',
                        }}
                      >
                        <div
                          style={{
                            height: `${virtualizer.getTotalSize()}px`,
                            width: '100%',
                            position: 'relative',
                          }}
                        >
                          {virtualOptions.map((virtualOption, i) => (
                            <CommandItem
                              style={{
                                position: 'absolute',
                                top: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                width: '100%',
                                height: `${virtualOption.size}px`,
                                transform: `translateY(${virtualOption.start}px)`,
                              }}
                              key={filteredOptions[virtualOption.index].value}
                              value={filteredOptions[virtualOption.index].value}
                              onSelect={(currentValue) => {
                                setSelectedOption(
                                  currentValue === selectedOption
                                    ? ''
                                    : currentValue,
                                );
                                form.setValue('service', field.value);
                                setOpen(false);
                              }}
                              className={cn(
                                'py-2',
                                i !== virtualOptions.length - 1 &&
                                  'border-b border-gray-200 py-2',
                              )}
                            >
                              {filteredOptions[virtualOption.index].label}
                              <CheckIcon
                                className={cn(
                                  'ml-auto h-4 w-4',
                                  filteredOptions[virtualOption.index].value ===
                                    field.value
                                    ? 'opacity-100'
                                    : 'opacity-0',
                                )}
                              />
                            </CommandItem>
                          ))}
                        </div>
                      </CommandGroup>
                    </CommandList>
                  </Command>
                </PopoverContent>
              </Popover>
              <FormDescription>
                This is the IT service do be updated.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}


Using useRef inside a hook that needs a reference for a DOM node that may not exist or change during the component's render (like popups, dialogs, etc.) may cause stale references or missed updates. To fix this, we need to use a callback ref. Using a callback ref ensures that the reference is updated whenever the DOM node changes, keeping the state consistent with the latest DOM element.
Instead of useRef, we can change it to useState so that we can track ref changes in the state and trigger re-renders as needed:
const [parentNode, setParentNode] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const virtualizer = useVirtualizer({
  count: filteredItems.length,
  getScrollElement: () => parentNode, // Use parentNode state here
  estimateSize: () => 35,
});

const refCallback = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
  if (node) {
    setParentNode(node);
  }
}, []);

Here, useState allows us to update the parentNode and trigger a re-render if the DOM node changes.
<CommandGroup> 
  {/* Move ref callback to CommandList */}
  <CommandList ref={refCallback}>
    <div 
      style={{
        height: virtualizer.getTotalSize(),
        width: "100%",
        position: "relative",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "100%",
          transform: `translateY(${virtualOptions[0]?.start}px)`,
        }}
      >
        {virtualOptions.map((virtualOption) => (
          <CommandItem
            value={filteredItems[virtualOption.index].value}
            data-index={virtualOption.index}
            key={virtualOption.key}
            ref={virtualizer.measureElement}
            onSelect={() => {}}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </CommandList>
</CommandGroup>


You should be able to solve this problem by using the useEffect hook and the measure() method provided by TanStack Virtual. Check out the documentation for more info about the method
  useEffect(() => {
    // If the popover is closed, there is no need to measure
    if (!open) {
      return;
    }

    rowVirtualizer.measure();
  }, [open, rowVirtualizer]);

The library calculates the virtual items for the first time when the component is rendered. Since the PopoverContent is not visible in the browser window when the component is rendered for the first time, the Virtual
library doesn't load the data.
